# SQL Triggers showing errors PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

This is my sql statements to write SQL trigger, that should be named FILM_LANG​, to append text to
the description of every new film inserted into the database. It is based on the
language (language_id) and the original language (original_language_id)
of the film.

Comment: Without debugging into details i think you just need some additional brackets. Oracle can't handle `TO_CHAR(SELECT ...`, you have to surround the inner select statement with additional brackets: `TO_CHAR((SELECT...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are querying the table language based on ids, it doesn't matter too much if you have them as two separate statements for a cleaner code.
By the way `CONCAT` function in Oracle works for two arguments only, so prefer `||`

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER "BI_FILM_LANG" 
  BEFORE INSERT ON "FILM" 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SELECT :NEW.description||'.Originally in ' 
           || name --no need to append :old.description, it's null for insert triggers. 
                   --Append :NEW.description if it contains anything before the string  
    INTO   :NEW.description 
    FROM   LANGUAGE 
    WHERE  language_id = :NEW.language_id; 

    SELECT :NEW.description 
           || '.Re-released in ' 
           || name --appends the :NEW.description 
    INTO   :NEW.description 
    FROM   LANGUAGE 
    WHERE  language_id = :NEW.original_language_id; 
END; 

/
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, this trigger works but the only issue is its not giving the right output forexample  If the following query was run:
INSERT INTO FILM (title, description, language_id,
original_language_id ) VALUES
('B Movie', 'Movie about wasps.', 1, 2);
It should produce the following when the select statement is run
Movie about wasps.Originally in Italian. Re-released in
English.  its only showing Originally in italian.Re-released in English and ignoring my provided description. I would really appreciate ur help. Thanks

Comment: @SidharthSachdev : Edited. Pls take a look You should append the :NEW.description before the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `concat` function,and putting more than parameters in it , that is the issue , instead you should use `||` to concatenate strings.